# Check if there is internet connection before fetching api in Laravel

Tags: laravel

```
$popularMovies=Http::withToken(config('services.tmdb.token'))
               ->get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular')
               ->json()['results'];
       
 $genreList=Http::withToken(config('services.tmdb.token'))
                ->get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular')
                ->json()['results'];

return view('index',compact('popularMovies'));
```

In above code I want to check if the client has internet connection, if not return with 'no internet connection'

The error I get if there is no internet connection: [image: error image]

Comment: php = server, which is not the client. So I suggest just doing the request like you are already doing and determine the next step based on that outcome.

Comment: Check if the call fails as a means to check if there's internet. This catches the possibility that either your server has no internet or the destination server is down (which can happen)